# How to add a bigger button item to UIToolbar in iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, uitoolbar

How to place a bigger button item to center of UIToolbar in iOS 7? Just as this shown:

I have tried with [this library](https://github.com/el-eleven/EEToolbarCenterButton), but it is not effect in iOS 7.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change the center property, check out these link

[Big button tutorial](http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/)